# Put request get ID | Axios, React, Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, put, axios

I want to make a PUT request to my server, but in order to do so I need an identifier for the specific object I need to update. And that is my problem, I don't know how to get the components id so I can fulfill my PUT request. Here's the code at the moment:

```
import axios from 'axios'
import settings from '../../../../settings'

axios.defaults.baseURL = settings.hostname

export const updateSettings = function(id, item) {
  return dispatch => {
    axios
      .put(`${settings.hostname}/locks/${id}`, item)
      .then(res => res.data)
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }
}
```

When console.log `item` I can see all the **new** thing I've typed in my input fields (the things I want to change), but I'm getting this also:
[image]

And sometimes `404`. So my question is how can I get the id so I can make this put request. Thank you.

This is where I call `updateSettings`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { updateSettings } from './redux/actions/updateSettingsAction'
import DoorSettingsForm from './components/doorsSettingsForm'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

class DoorSettingsContainer extends Component {
  submit(values) {
    this.props.updateSettings(values)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <DoorSettingsForm
          onSubmit={this.submit.bind(this)}
          item={this.props.location.state.item}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { data: state.data }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { updateSettings })(
  DoorSettingsContainer
)
```

Comment: How do you call `updateSettings`? Looks like you are passing in an object instead of just a primitive.

Comment: I've added some code.

Comment: what does the values object look like?

Answer (score 0):

What you are currently doing is passing the event object received by the `onSubmit` handler to the `updateSettings` method.

Mind that in your event handler you have access to both `state` and `props`:

```
submit() {
  // this comes from the redux binding
  const { data } = this.props
  // this is local state, not sure what else of interest is in there
  const item = this.state.location.item

  // Just a guess, inspect your data to see what's appropriate here.
  this.props.updateSettings(data.id, item)
}
```

Inspect your data, you probably need to access `data.id` or `item.id` to get the proper id `updateSettings` needs.

Also pay attention that if you are dispatching async actions this way, then depending on what middleware you are using, you will probably have to call `dispatch` when the async data comes in (e.g. where you can access `res.data`).

Answer (score 0):

You've missed the id on the `updateSettings()` function

look at this line: `export const updateSettings = function(id, item) {};`

and then the line where you call it:

```
submit(values) {
    this.props.updateSettings(values)
}
```

your item is your id here, and the item is nowhere to be found, i think this is where you get most of your problems atleast for now from.